# Select selecionando o atendente abaixo da media de chamados

Tags: mysql

Bom dia,

Estos tentando fazer um select para selecionar apenas os atendentes que tiverem o numero de chamados abaixo da media.

Parece simples, mas não estou conseguindo, já tentei de varias maneiras...

No teria que contar o numero de chamados o no WHERE colocar algo do tipo "Count(*) < $media"

Obrigado.

$media = '40';

```
SELECT a.adminID
    from os
    JOIN cadastroCliente cc ON cc.cadastroClienteID = os.idcliente
    JOIN administrador a ON a.adminID = os.idusuario
    WHERE os.idusuario = a.adminID
    AND os.status = '1'
    AND os.respondido = '0'
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Por que não faz então a contagem primeiro, e dá um return $row[contagem]; e no próximo SQL faz uma nova consulta com o count..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você terá que usar `having` para isto, aqui está um exemplo:

```
SELECT count(a.adminID), a.adminID
    from os
    JOIN cadastroCliente cc ON cc.cadastroClienteID = os.idcliente
    JOIN administrador a ON a.adminID = os.idusuario
    WHERE os.idusuario = a.adminID
    AND os.status = '1'
    AND os.respondido = '0'
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1

group by adminID
having count(a.adminID) < 40
```